# vmware-clarity component complete reference

Tags: vmware-clarity

Where can I find a complete reference for vmware-clarity components?

I'm writing web UI with datagrid, dropdown listbox, combobox, chart, etc, but I didn't find the complete reference for them.

Answer (score 2):

There are documentation pages for all of the Clarity components here: https://vmware.github.io/clarity/

These are a mix of design guidelines, usually at the top of the components documentation page. And then below, the Clarity Angular component examples describing the declarative API for each component with one or more examples.

Comment: While the existing documentation is fantastic, I still can't seem to find where it lists the available angular components. For example, if you read the documentation you find out you should have a <div> with a "main-content" class on it in your page. But then later, after reading examples around you find out that there is actually a <clr-main-container> component that presumably works just like the aforementioned div. Which should we use and why/why not? This kind of documentation would be great.

Comment: Hi @dwoodwardgb - thanks for the feedback. We are working on improving the docs so hearing your experience helps. 

Clarity ships as several libraries: `@clr/ui` (standalone html/css) and `@clr/angular` (Angular components). Any markup that uses the `clr-` prefix to the element is an `@clr/angular` component and will generate the dom structure need for styling with Clarity CSS. If the app isn't using angular but using `@clr/ui` you need to follow the DOM structure in the docs. Does this help?  I'll make note of your feedback so that we can try to address the differences that you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@beeman/tutorial-project-clarity-and-angular-cli-50d845a24d5b

This is a nice article (at least I started with it) on using `vmware-clarity` with `Angular CLI`.

The author of the article has a demo project here in Github: https://github.com/beeman/tutorial-angular-styling-clarity which runs live here: https://beeman.github.io/tutorial-angular-styling-clarity/tutorial-angular-styling-clarity/.